# Selecting a Next button between two different pages when Back shows up

Tags: selenium

I'm working on a page object to include a Next button (which is easy enough for the first part) - however when I get to the next page, there is now a Back button as well as another Next button which I can get to with:

`//*[@id="fieldset2"]/input[2]`

The problem is that if I try to use the same method for clicking Next, the location of the button is not the same between the first and second pages. I wanted to pass the value on input as the index of the button - but I'm not sure how I'd even go about that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you clearly mentioned that you are `working on a page object` why would you  `try to use the same method` ? Wouldn't the PageFactory different?

Comment: I suppose because both buttons are labled 'Next' - I wanted to have just one method of taking care of them, rather than having two different methods for what looks like the same button - if that makes sense?

Comment: From a different perspective you may​be right in case you are using the WebDriver in-built method to traverse back. Need to look at how you implemented.